# In AVA How can I import a variable from a test file to another test file

Tags: import, automated-tests, export, ava

I am using AVA for testing.  I have 2 files.  In file1.spec.js, I am creating a user, and once the user is created a userId is generated and returned.  I need this userId in file2.spec.js to test some other API calls specific to this user. How can I successfully export the userId created in file1.spec.js and import it into file2.spec.js?  Thanks in advance!

I have tried the following:

file1.spec.js:

method: 'POST',
        url:    '/api/users',
        data:   setupFixture.postUsersAtLocation1
    }).catch(err => { console.log(err.response.data); return err.response; });

```
if (result.status === 200) {
    _int.userId = result.data.userId;
```

SCENARIO 1:
module.exports = {userId, userId1};

SCENARIO 2:
 export {userId1}; 
 export let userId = _int.userId;

file2.spec.js:

import test from 'ava';

import setup from './setup.spec.js';

const {userId, userId1} = setup;

var userIdA = userId;
var userId1A = userId1;

When I run this, it complains that file2.spec.js has an unexpected identifier (test) in import test from 'ava'.  If I remove "import setup from './setup.spec.js';", and all after it, it no longer complains about test, but I never get the variables imported, either way.

Answer (score 0):

Each test file is executed in a new worker process. Test files should not depend on another file having been executed first. Instead try and use a different database / table / IDs in each test file, then share setup code (if necessary) through helpers.